# Conflict between mototools and javascript both not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, shared-libraries, mootools, conflict

I have a conflict between JavaScript and Mototools, I know there is something like NoConflict script but I do not fully understand how can I make it work  I will leave the code of both dependencies so that It can be explained also I think It can be very useful for people who have encounter the same conflict, If one works the other one won't. you can see it I made it partially work but not totally www.softglobal.com.mx. Thank you

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.2.pack.js" ></script>

        <script type='text/javascript'  src="  

         http://static.tumblr.com/5bbaxlr/2tlmqkzma/mototools.js">

      </script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var hoveroptions = {
    animout:                        'JAMenuhover_fade',
    animin:                         'JAMenuhover_fade',
    duration:                       400,
    transition:             Fx.Transitions.linear};
    window.addEvent ('domready', function (){
    if ($('ja-mainnav')) {
                    var items = $$('#ja-mainnav li a');
            new JAMenuhover (items,hoveroptions );
    }
   });
   //]]>
   </script>
```

This make on mouse over a drag effect which looks fantastic but then I got this which was my previous question

```
     <script type="text/javascript"           
     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/
     jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js">
     </script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[  
     jQuery(function() {
    var request = window.location.hash;
    if(request == '#page-2') {
    jQuery('.page.current').removeClass('current');
    jQuery('.page').eq(1).addClass('current');
     }
    jQuery('div ul li').click(function(){
    var speed = 600;
    var i = $(this).index();
    jQuery('.page.current').animate({opacity: 0, marginTop:80},speed,function(){
        jQuery(this).removeClass('current');
        jQuery('.page').eq(i).css('marginTop',30).animate({opacity:1,marginTop:    

         50},speed).addClass('current');        
         });
         });
         });

        //]]>
       </script>
```

Comment: @ Alex: I don't know anything about MotoTools

Comment: Did you get this working? You didn't tag Mootools so you missed people than can help you on this.

Comment: Not that yo guys care or want to know but I was in a robbery where my laptops and portable HDD where stolen with all my work here, so I don't have a way to support my self so I'm off doing this until I recover which won't be soon, dangerous country.. so no I don't have anything to try it. sorry and thanks for asking

Answer (score 1):

I believe you mean [MooTools](http://mootools.net/download) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) not MoToTools and JavaScript.

You *can* technically combine these 2 libraries together and make them work. This is however **not recommended**, since they both do similar things and including them on page side by side brings a ***lot of overhead***, resulting in slow page rendering.

That being said, this is an example how you can use them both:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.4.5/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>

<p>jQuery sets this paragraph's color to red but MooTools sets the border color.</p>

<script>
//no conflict jquery
jQuery.noConflict();
//jquery stuff
(function($) {
    $('p').css('color','#ff0000');
})(jQuery);

//moo stuff
window.addEvent('domready',function() {
    $$('p').setStyle('border','1px solid #fc0');
});
</script>
```

**NOTE:** the versions of jQuery and MooTools displayed in your question are quite outdated and it's unlikely they will work in newer browsers without many glitches and hiccups, therefore I used the newest versions of both libraries in my answer

Working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9zLQV/

Source for the example code: http://davidwalsh.name/jquery-mootools

Comment: I just replayed to let know what happened and how I am unable to try.. you can see the answer above, so thank you for answering hope to find out if it works soon.